# What are my options for accessing an SQL Server database through MS Access front-end while offline

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm currently working on a project proposal which would require moving multiple Access databases into a new MS SQL Server database. The idea is to keep the front end program as MS Access so that the users are familiar with the process of inputting data and creating reports.

However, things get complicated in that the internet in the areas where the survey will be collected has poor connectivity and will be out from time to time. I had thought of a few ways of solving this issue but all of them are cumbersome:

1) Having a PC with a router that stores the SQL Server database in offline mode and the data entry PCs connect to the PC with the offline database through the router. The PC with the SQL Server database can then backup the db on the server when it has an internet connection.

2) Adding the data to MS Access databases that can then be merged with the SQL Server at specified increments (this would probably cause some issues).

We've done option 1 before for similar projects but never for connecting to an SQL Server database in offline mode. However, it seems feasible.

My question is: Does anyone know of a way of using Access as a front end application for SQL Server and being able to update data during times without internet connectivity? The SQL Server database would automatically assign primary keys, so, duplicate unique values shouldn't be an issue while syncing the data.

Thanks for your help. I've been having a hard time finding an answer on Google and syncing to databases is complicated at the best of times. I'm really just looking for a starting point to see if there are easier ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: you're right, this is difficult. Your option 2 is probably the best bet with the access db having a full copy of all of the tables in sql server. your code will have to dynamically check the connectivity any time it access data, and if the connection is down, read and write to local access db, then try to sync when the connection comes up. you'll have alot of issues of data collision if many folks are trying to edit the same records. its a really tough problem with not a whole lot of good solutions if you want to keep access as your front end.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I had thought about this. I think I can swing it so edits can't be made without access to the internet - It would just be adding data. So, I wouldn't need to worry about people editing the same record. However, the database would be too large to be stored in a single database as well, so, the records would have to be deleted after they are re-uploaded which would add another layer of difficultly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run a the free editon of SQL express on all laptops. So the Access database would be the front end to the local edition of SQL express. SQL express can be a subscriber to the "main" sql database. You thus use SQL replication to sync those local editions of SQL server to the master server. Of course the main SQL server can't be the free edition of SQL server. So to publish the database for replication, you can't use the free edition, but those free editions can certainly be used as subscribers.

This approach would eliminate the need to build or write special software for the Access application. You thus do a traditional migration of the access back end (data tables) to sql server, and then simply run the Access application local with sql express installed on each laptop. You then fire off a sync to the main edition of sql server when such laptops are back at the office.

The other possible would be to adopt and use the net sync framework. This would also allow sync, and would eliminate the need to run sql expess on each machine. I think the least amount of effort is to sync the local editions of sql express with the main editon of SQL server running at the office (but that office edition of SQL server can't be a free edition).

Comment: This seems like it might work for me. I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks Albert!